# Unable to find 'unicode/utypes.h' in icu compile

Tags: cygwin, icu

An earlier attempt to compile ICU for Windows using MSVC and Cygwin worked fine. This time, however, after a successful

> .../icu/source/runConfigureICU Cygwin/MSVC

**make** ends with the following error:

> .../icu/source/stubdata/stubdata.c(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot
>   open include file: 'unicode/utypes.h': No such file or directory

No problems with the non-MSVC Cygwin version. I am in a different directory, but it seems that this worked before.

**Update.** I must have compiled it in the icu/source directory before. I went back and did runConfigureICU in-place and did not see the error. I feel sad that I have to ruin my pristine icu folder, but perhaps there is no other way to compile Cygwin/MSVC. It might have something to do with how the Microsoft compiler handles paths.

**Update2.** making it in icu/source makes the other location work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that runConfigureICU can only be called for Cygwin/MSVC in the icu/sources directory, otherwise, cl cannot get to the cygwin-based include path.